# How do I set DateTimes universally to local time in view engine?

Tags: c#, .net

I am storing DateTimes in my db using UniversalTime. In my views/controllers, I was hoping to convert them to Local Time. Is there a way to do this other than calling .ToLocalTime() in my controller on each individual DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom display template for `DateTime`.

```
@model System.DateTime

@Model.ToLocalTime()
```

Comment: I tried that and no change. I don't have to decorate my ViewModels a certain way do I? As long as their type is DateTime, right?

Comment: Nope. Make sure its named `DateTime.cshtml`.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I had, which is why I'm confused. Because it's still displaying UTC Time.

Comment: is your server set to UTC time?

Comment: Nope. Wish it were that simple.

Comment: How is the property getting assigned?

Comment: Through an anonymous type. Would that matter?